# Either Jack or you ......... doing this - Fill in the blank

Tags: sentence-structure, subject-verb-agreement

> Either Jack or you _____ doing this

Options:

1) was

2) were

3) is

4) had

My approach:

According to the subject verb agreement rule. 'Either' in the sentence should be followed by a singular form of the verb. So, according to my logic the answer should be "was".

Am I correct?

Comment: As per my knowledge, I would prefer 'were' with 'you'. Let the native speakers come. Btw, very interesting question! I would like to consider 'had' as well, but then, we need to put 'been' after had, I guess!

Comment: As far as I know, if we have plural noun in the phrase " X or Y" ( one of the X or Y is plural or both of X and Y), we must use plural verbs. However, **you** can represent both singular and plural. That is my problem ! So lets wait for the natives !

Comment: If you like 'was', then 'is' is just as valid.  Nothing in the question gives a clue as to tense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct in thinking that the singular form of the verb should be used, but the singular past tense of 'be' can be 'I was', 'You were', or 'He/She/It was'. As the verb follows 'you', it should be 'were'.

Comment: this better goes as a comment iMO

Comment: So how do you feel about "Either Jack or I am doing this" ?

Comment: @MaulikV Not really - it’s an answer.

Comment: @amI A native English speaker would say “Either Jack or I are doing this”, but it still sounds odd. “Either Jack or I will do it” is better.or “Jack’s doing it or I am”.

Comment: I think that contradicts your answer.  You are choosing plural agreement, not agreement with the pronoun.

Comment: My answer was to the statement referring to “Jack or you”, and my comment above refers to the statement about “Jack or I”. It’s “Jack or you were...” and “Jack or I are”. No contradiction. Although, on reflection, certain UK dialects could use “Jack or I am...”

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between

Either jack was doing this and

Either jack or you were doing this.

In the formal sentence,we use a singular verb always where as in the latter

It depends If both are singular nouns we use a singular verb and if one of them is plural we use a plural verb.In this Example We use a plural verb based on "you".Hence were.